# Mobile only issue: JavaScript :TypeError: document.getElementById(…) is null

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML and script:

```
<div class="gk-cols" data-cols="3">

  <div class="myclass">
    <a href="#" class="otherclass"><img alt="myalt" src="myimage.png"> <strong><span data-sr="enter bottom" data-count=""><div id="counter_1"></div></span><span>units <strong><span class="anotherclass">Name</span></strong> used</span></strong></a>
  </div>

  <div class="myclass">
    <a href="#" class="otherclass"><img alt="myalt" src="myimage.png"> <strong><span data-sr="enter bottom" data-count=""><div id="counter_2"></div></span><span>units <strong><span class="anotherclass">Name</span></strong> used</span></strong></a>
  </div>

  <div class="myclass">
    <img alt="myalt" src="myimage.png"> <strong><span data-sr="enter bottom" data-count=""><div id="counter_3">

    mytext

    <div class="otherclass">
      <span class="anotherclass" style="display: inline-block; visibility: visible; position: relative;">
        <span class="classissima"></span>
        <span class="classagain">
          other text
        </span>
        <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 92 92" class="loader">
          <circle class="bar" cx="46" cy="46" r="43"/>
          <circle class="path" cx="46" cy="46" r="43"/>
        </svg>
      </span>
    </div>

    </div></span><span> text<strong><psna class="classagain">Name</psna></strong> used</span></strong>
  </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var START_DATE_1 = new Date('July 18, 2016 10:30:00').getTime(); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL_1 = 4; // in seconds
    var INCREMENT_1 = 1; // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE_1 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
    var msInterval_1 = INTERVAL_1 * 1200;
    var now_1 = Date.now();
    var count_1 = Math.trunc((now_1 - START_DATE_1) / msInterval_1) * INCREMENT_1 + START_VALUE_1;

    function formatNumber(number) {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat('it').format(number);
    }

    document.getElementById('counter_1').textContent = formatNumber(count_1);
    setInterval(function() {
      count_1 += INCREMENT_1;
      document.getElementById('counter_1').textContent = formatNumber(count_1);
    }, msInterval_1);




    var START_DATE_2 = new Date('July 18, 2016 10:30:00').getTime(); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL_2 = 7; // in seconds
    var INCREMENT_2 = 1; // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE_2 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
    var msInterval_2 = INTERVAL_2 * 2500;
    var now_2 = Date.now();
    var count_2 = Math.trunc((now_2 - START_DATE_2) / msInterval_2) * INCREMENT_2 + START_VALUE_2;

    function formatNumber(number) {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat('it').format(number);
    }

    document.getElementById('counter_2').textContent = formatNumber(count_2);
    setInterval(function() {
      count_2 += INCREMENT_2;
      document.getElementById('counter_2').textContent = formatNumber(count_2);
    }, msInterval_2);
  });
</script>
```

Now, the script works fine in desktop view, but as soon as I reduce the windows size (mobile size) and reload, or just check my page with a smartphone I got an error: "JavaScript :TypeError: document.getElementById(…) is null" and also the counters are empty.

Why?

Comment: [Works fine on my phone.](https://jsfiddle.net/s28ojtfL/) Perhaps you have some other code elsewhere that removes those elements on mobile devices.

Comment: I supposed it too but I'm not able to find and check... can you suggest me some tools to find a possible conflict?

Comment: I don't really debug mobile often. Search for "mobile debugging " and the name of the browser you're using. You'll find something.

Comment: I think I can do it for desktop, beacuse the issue is present even when I reduce the browser window size simulating a mobile screen. I need to reload the page in that case to generate the error. Anyway I'm not able to debug it with FireFox and Firebug, it just says that "JavaScript :TypeError: document.getElementById(…) is null"

Comment: Then you need to find out when those elements are getting removed. I'm not sure about Firefox but I know in Chrome you can go to the Elements tab, find the node you're interested, and tell it to "break" whenever that node is removed. That will point you to the problem.

Comment: With Chrome I've found this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null(…) . I don't know what to do with it...

Comment: ... It's the same problem. Listen, you need to figure out *why* you're getting `null`. You get `null` from `document.getElementById` when no element with that ID exists.

Comment: Might be nothing to do with your issue, but you do have some invalid HTML in there. For instance, you shouldn't have a `<div>` nested in a `<span>`, and you have a `<psna>` tag that's probably a misspelled `<span>`.  Your HTML has a lot of nesting going on, which could probably be reduced considerably (which could speed up rendering).

Comment: Meanwhile You was answering Mike MCCaughan I found the issue! :-) First of all I tryed to mode the id="counter_1" from the div to the span and tested: it worked fine!